# Laravel Validation: grouped validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am attempting to add validation to my request validator for a group of fields to make sure that the group of fields does not exceed a certain amount.  Once a user submits their form, they can view it in pdf form and my objective is to make sure that the collection of `f_name`, `m_name` and `l_name` does not run into another group of text on the pdf (thus making it illegible).

Essentially, I want something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'f_name' + 'm_name' + 'l_name' => 'max:50',
    ...
  ];
}
```

I have searched all over but the only questions I can find related are simply how to do validation.  If anyone knows how to group values in validation or links to previously asked questions, please let me know.  Thanks mates.

Comment: I think you can use a custom validator and pass it multiple fields to it, here there is an example a bit old but I believe it still works http://laravel.io/forum/11-09-2014-create-custom-validation-rule-which-takes-two-fields-as-arguments

Comment: Do you want  `=> 'max:50',`  should be applied to all `'f_name' + 'm_name' + 'l_name'`?

Comment: @Abbasi applying 'max:50' to each field would give me a total max of 150 which would then run across other text on the page.  I am looking for the 3 collectively to not exceed 50.

Comment: In that case, I think custom validator would be good option as mentioned by @Igomezma

Comment: Indeed.  I am looking into that currently.  I have never messed with extending core Laravel before so it will probably take me awhile to figure out where to extend it at and how.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not support multifields validation with one rules stack. Try write custom validator or reinvent the wheel:

```
public function rules()
{
    $fields = [
        "max: 50" => ["f_name", "m_name", "l_name"]
    ];
    $rules = [];

    foreach($fields as $rule => $fieldArray){
        if(is_array($fieldArray)){
            foreach($fieldArray as $field){
                $rules[$field] = $rule; 
            } 
        }
    }
  return $rules;
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want each one to be max 50, he wants the concatenation to be max 50.

Comment: @JoelHinz okay) thanx, I just read comment) then he should use custom validator)

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom validator so you can add several fields.
In your AppServiceProvider, something like this:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('groupedFieldsLongerThan50', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $f_name = array_get($this->data, $parameters[0]);
            $m_name = array_get($this->data, $parameters[1]);
            $l_name = array_get($this->data, $parameters[2]);

            if((strlen($f_name)+strlen($m_name)+strlen($l_name))<=50)
                  return true;

            return false;
        });
    }

    ...
```

Where you are declaring your rules add:

```
'f_name' => 'groupedFieldsLongerThan50:f_name,m_name,l_name'
```

Comment: This is giving me an `Undefined variable: data` error because `$this` = `AppServiceProvider` and not `Validator`... any way to fix this?  I tried changing `$this` to `$validator` but I cannot access its protected properties.